# Docker / Flask - Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server

Tags: python, docker, flask

everyone. I try to use Docker. I follow this guide:

https://cloud.croc.ru/blog/byt-v-teme/flask-prilozheniya-v-docker/

My app.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Moe Flask приложение в контейнере Docker.'
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-add-repository -y universe
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app 
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ['python']
CMD ['app.py']
```

App is working by itself, but in Docker returns:

```
Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
```

I use Win7 x64, and Docker Quickstart Terminal

Thank you.

**UPD**

Thing is I build with:

docker run -d -p **5000**:**5000** my_flask_app:v0.1

But in browser use:

http://192.168.99.100:2376/

Added in Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
EXPOSE 2376/tcp
```

Result is the same

**UPD2**

Tried to use

```
docker run -d -p 2376:2376 my_flask_app:v0.1
```

But error appears: ***port is already allocated***

docker ps - empty

docker ps -a - gives my_flask_app container

I use docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q) to delete all containers, then

docker ps -a is empty

But again I see ***port is already allocated***

Comment: you need to expose the port of your app in dockerfile

Comment: added expose 5000/tcp and expose 2376/tcp, rebuilded = not working

Comment: check `http://localhost:5000` ?

Comment: This site can’t be reached. http://localhost:2376 is not working too

Comment: What port does your flask app works ?

Comment: ...........2376

Comment: Run with this : 
docker run -d -p 2376:2376 my_flask_app:v0.1 and then check the localhost:2376

Comment: Port is already allocated. Updated topic. Thank you

Comment: you can map it to different port then 
docker run -d -p 2375:2376 my_flask_app:v0.1 and then check the localhost:2375 –

Comment: Sadly, no. localhost and http://192.168.99.100:2375/ are not working